# I'm trying to use Log4j2's Rabbit Appender, but my program reports an error

Tags: rabbitmq, log4j2, amqp

my Log4j2.xml

```
<Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p %C{2} - %m%n"/>
</Console>
<RabbitMQ name="rabbitmq"
          virtualHost="/"
          exchange="" exchangeType="direct" declareExchange="true" durable="true" autoDelete="false"
          host="127.0.0.1"
          port="5672"
          user="admin"
          password="1234"
          applicationId="myAppId" routingKeyPattern="%X{applicationId}.%c.%p"
          contentType="text/plain" contentEncoding="UTF-8"
          generateId="true"
          deliveryMode="NON_PERSISTENT"
          charset="UTF-8"
          senderPoolSize="3"
          maxSenderRetries="5">
    <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
</RabbitMQ>
```

When my program starts I get an error like this

```
ERROR Error processing element RabbitMQ ([Appenders: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
ERROR Unable to locate appender "rabbitmq" for logger config "root"
```

I'm guessing maybe I'm missing some dependencies

Hope someone can help me, thanks

Comment: When I renamed log4j2.xml to log4j2-spring.xml, the problem was solved.